# Expect script not showing script execution on console

Tags: shell, expect

Have written an expect script for an installation by providing default values. It is not installing properly and also during execution, it is not execution progress on console.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

cd /opt/hyperic-hqee-agent-5.8.6
exec rm -rf data
cd bin
exec ./hq-agent.sh stop
exec ./hq-agent.sh start
expect ": $"
send "\r"
expect ": $"
send "10.152.24.109\r"
expect ": $"
send "\r"
expect ": $"
send "\r"
expect ": $"
send "\r"
expect ": $"
send "hqadmin\r"
expect ": $"
send "\r"
expect ": $"
send "\r"
expect ": $"
send "yes\r"
```

Comment: When you say "it is not installing properly," what is the error message, or what is going wrong?  What kind of execution progress do you expect on console?

Comment: I am trying to automate installation of an application by stopping existing one. It will be expecting some inputs during the course of installation of which most are default. So sending '\r' for that. It is not displaying any error message also. It is going to a loop and getting struck at 'exec ./hq-agent.sh start' and not doing further. It is not displaying interactions on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the mistake I did. Instead of 'exec', I should have used 'spawn'. It was going just as a shell command and was not interacting.

```
cd bin
spawn ./hq-agent.sh stop
expect ":$"
spawn ./hq-agent.sh start
expect ": $"
send "\r"
expect ": $"
.
..
.
interact
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

The `exec` command *returns* stdout. If you want to print it, use

```
puts [exec external_command]
```